# Pure HTML/CSS vertical menu on left onclick showing content on the right (without JavaScript)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a menu on the left side showing the content on the right without using JavaScript.

```css
.treeview ul{ /*CSS for Simple Tree Menu*/
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.treeview li{ /*Style for LI elements in general (excludes an LI that contains sub lists)*/
background: white no-repeat left center;
list-style-type: none;
padding-left: 22px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.treeview li.submenu{ /* Style for LI that contains sub lists (other ULs). */
background: white url(list.gif) no-repeat left 1px;
cursor: hand !important;
cursor: pointer !important;
}


.treeview li.submenu ul{ /*Style for ULs that are children of LIs (submenu) */
display: none; /*Hide them by default. Don't delete. */
}

.treeview .submenu ul li{ /*Style for LIs of ULs that are children of LIs (submenu) */
cursor: default;
}

div.container {
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid gray;
}

header, footer {
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    clear: left;
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    float: left;
    max-width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2em;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}
   
nav ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

article {
 position:relative;
    margin-left: 160px;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 10em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="simpletree.css" />


</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

<header>
   <h1>Documentation</h1>
</header>
  
<nav>
<h4>Main Menu:</h4>


<ul id="treemenu" class="treeview">
<div class="collapse" tabindex="1">
<a href=""><li>Menu 1</li></a>
</div>
<li>Menu 2</li>

<li>Menu 3
 <ul>
 <li>Sub Item 3.1</li>
 <li>Sub Item 3.2</li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li>Menu 4</li>
<li>Menu 5
 <ul>
 <li>Sub Item 5.1</li>
 <li>Menu 5.1
  <ul>
  <li>Sub Item 5.1.1</li>
  <li>Sub Item 5.1.2</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</li>

<li>Menu 6</li>
</ul>

</nav>

<article>
  <h1>Menu 1</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </article>



<footer></footer>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm not able to create showing the content on the right on click on Menu1 and then removing the content and showing another content clicking on Menu2 using only pure HTML/CSS

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: I did in the example above

Comment: Without js? it's impossible i think

Comment: Without JS, the only way to do it is with iFrames (not recommended) or with using multiple HTML files.

Comment: That's literally just a layout. What have you tried to solve your problem? (also, I agree with Gene and paolo above)

Comment: Iframe are the evi... read this article: http://www.rwblackburn.com/iframe-evil/

Comment: @J.Titus: I was not able to organize the css file due to a lack of knowledge, i have searched for an example,  but was not able to find any matching my criteria. I found some similar examles using display:block; but wasnt able to implement them in the css and make them work. I will try the below :target solution which looks exactly what im trying to do. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible option would be to use `:target` pseudo-class to show the `article`.

Quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target):

> The **:target** pseudo-class represents the unique element, if any, with
>   an id matching the fragment identifier of the URI of the document.

Here is a sample snippet which demonstrate the same:

```css
/** Menu content styles **/

article {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 160px;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 10em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.menuContent {
  display: none;
}
#menu1Content:target {
  display: block;
}
#menu2Content:target {
  display: block;
}
#menu3Content:target {
  display: block;
}
/** Menu styles **/

.treeview ul {
  /*CSS for Simple Tree Menu*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.treeview li {
  /*Style for LI elements in general (excludes an LI that contains sub lists)*/
  background: white no-repeat left center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
div.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid gray;
}
header,
footer {
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
}
nav {
  float: left;
  max-width: 250px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2em;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <header>
    <h1>Documentation</h1>
  </header>

  <nav>
    <h4>Main Menu:</h4>
    <!-- Menu -->
    <ul id="treemenu" class="treeview">
      <div class="collapse" tabindex="1">
        <a href="#menu1Content">
          <li>Menu 1</li>
        </a>
      </div>
      <li>
        <a href="#menu2Content">Menu 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#menu3Content">Menu 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <!-- Menu Contents -->
  <article id="menu1Content" class="menuContent">
    <h1>Menu 1</h1>
    <p>Contents of menu 1...</p>
  </article>

  <article id="menu2Content" class="menuContent">
    <h1>Menu 2</h1>
    <p>Contents of menu 2...</p>
  </article>

  <article id="menu3Content" class="menuContent">
    <h1>Menu 3</h1>
    <p>Contents of menu 3...</p>
  </article>

  <footer></footer>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , that was exactly what I was looking for . Thank you for the example !

Answer (score 1):

If you're after what I think you're after, ie - clicking on one item in the menu, for so to display the content on the right, that is completely possible, but you will have to make some changes.

First and foremost, move the `<a>` inside the `<li>` - wrapping a `<li>`-element in a `<a>` is not valid HTML.

Then you put a link to the container you want to show in the `href` of said `<a>` - for this response, say you change the `href` to `href="article1"`. Then you find the corresponding article, and give that `id="article1"`.

In your CSS, you give all the articles `display: none;` (so they're hidden by default), and set up a CSS-rule for when they're targeted. You can do this, making it possible to attach the `:target`-event to multiple IDs by using `[id^=article]:target` - that will attach to every ID that start with "article". Then you set that back to `display: block;`and you will see the article you just clicked on.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! If I could mark 2 answers your explanation would be marked as well !